# Converting csv files data to an array using php str_getcsv function

Tags: php, arrays, loops, fgetcsv, fputcsv

I have string like which is created using [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

```
Date,Name,Hours 2013-01-02,"Test User",7:59 2013-01-03,"Test User",7:53 2013-01-04,"Test User",8:12 2013-01-07,"Test User",7:56 2013-01-08,"Test User",8:25 2013-01-09,"Test User",7:56 2013-01-10,"Test User",8:10 2013-01-11,"Test User",7:53 2013-01-14,"Test User",7:54 2013-01-15,"Test User",0:34 2013-04-01,"Test User",5:51 2013-04-02,"Test User",8:50 2013-04-03,"Test User",7:25 2013-04-04,"Test User",8:3 2013-04-05,"Test User","10:42:52[Not punch out]" ,Total,103:1
```

when proper header (header('Content-type: application/csv'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');) is set it gives correct csv file.

[image: Converting csv files data to an array using php str_getcsv]

But I want this string again to be converted to a array format so I tried passing above string to [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) but getting array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Date
    [1] => Name
    [2] => Hours
2013-01-02
    [3] => "Allen Herrera"
    [4] => 7:59
2013-01-03
    [5] => "Allen Herrera"
    [6] => 7:53
2013-01-04
    [7] => "Allen Herrera"
    [8] => 8:12
2013-01-07
    [9] => "Allen Herrera"
    [10] => 7:56
2013-01-08
    [11] => "Allen Herrera"
    [12] => 8:25
2013-01-09
    [13] => "Allen Herrera"
    [14] => 7:56
2013-01-10
    [15] => "Allen Herrera"
    [16] => 8:10
2013-01-11
    [17] => "Allen Herrera"
    [18] => 7:53
2013-01-14......................
```

Can you help me to get properly formatted array so that I can easily use it to create table looping on the array.

Comment: I think you need to `explode()` it using `PHP_EOL` as delimiter and then use each part in `str_getcsv()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After little searching got solution on this

```
$data = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $string_data));
print_r($data);
```

Giving me array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Date
            [1] => Name
            [2] => Hours
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-02
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 7:59
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-03
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 7:53
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-04
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 8:12
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-07
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 7:56
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-08
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 8:25
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-09
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 7:56
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-01-10
            [1] => Test User
            [2] => 8:10
        )...
```

Comment: I would like to recommend a trick in order to add arguments for `str_getcsv` function. Try:

$contents = Storage::get('folder/file.csv');
$filterCsv = function ($arg) { return str_getcsv($arg, ';', '"', '\r\n'); };
$mapped = array_map($filterCsv, preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $contents));

Answer (score 5):

```
 $file = file_get_contents("test.csv");
 $data = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file));
 print_r($data);
```

Comment: This will not give me array how I exactly want.

Answer (score 2):

That will be something like:

```
$parts = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
$array = array();
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($part);
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: if `PHP_EOL` doesn't work, try different delimiters (`"\n"`, `"\r\n"`, `"\r"`).

Answer (score 2):

I use this way to converting csv files data to an array:-

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);/// (PHP's detection of line endings) write at the top.


$csvrows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filepath));
$csvheader = array_shift($csvrows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($csvrows as $row) {
   $csv[] = array_combine($csvheader, $row);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $path = 'uploads/my_csvfile.csv';
 $file_content = file_get_contents($path);
 $matches = array_map('str_getcsv', preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/',$file_content));
 print_r($matches);
```